# Running docker exec in parallel on the same container

Tags: docker

Not able to find the answer.
I have one docker container. We have scheduled jobs(5 jobs) in Jenkins will run docker exec on this container. So if we run docker exec in parallel, does it work, is there any issue.
I understand if jobs are writing to same file etc...

```
They all run in parallel , container is same

docker exec  <container> /bin/bash -c "python xyz.c"

another job
docker exec  <container> /bin/bash -c "python abc.c"

another job
docker exec  <container> /bin/bash -c "python abc100.c"
...
```

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? You are running parallel tasks and it doesn't work for you or this is more of a general curiosity type of question about where that would potentially work?

Comment: Do these tasks need to run inside an existing container; can you `docker run -d` a separate container for each instead, and then `docker wait` for them all to finish?

Comment: @jabbson : Let's say I run docker exec and its running for a while. While this is still running,  I will run another exec from another terminal(I will do 3 more like this).  Does this create any problem?

Comment: Given said processes can be executed together, and they cumulatively do not exhaust available resources no, this should not create any problem.

Comment: Thanks all for the response.

Comment: I think its basically interesting question, can we run docker exec in parallel, will the network sockets, that are used to communicate to the container, handle it?